# I'm having an issue with liip imagine

Tags: php, apache, symfony, symfony5, liipimaginebundle

I use symfony 5.4 and I just install the package liip imagine to manipulate my images. However after configuring everything, I don't have any image appearing in my browser and when I inspect, I get my code, I get the following error message: http://localhost:8000/media/cache/resolve/my_thumb/images/properties/629a464aa81ef086062845.jpg 404 (Not Found)

in my project, I even don't have any directory auto-generated for media/cache/.....  in the images directory.

this is the content of my liip_imagine.yaml file:

```
# Documentation on how to configure the bundle can be found at: https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/LiipImagineBundle/basic-usage.html
liip_imagine:
    # valid drivers options include "gd" or "gmagick" or "imagick"
    driver: "gd"

    filter_sets:
        cache : ~
        my_thumb:
            quality: 75
            filters:
                thumbnails: {size: [360, 230], mode: outbound}
```

and this is what I've wrote in my twig file:

```
<img src="{{ vich_uploader_asset(property, 'imageFile') | imagine_filter('my_thumb') }}" class="card-img-top" alt="">
```

please I need help I've tried several tricks like adding resolver and loaders but none of them solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

Use this setting also in config file

```
resolvers:
    default:
        web_path:
            web_root: ~ # %kernel.project_dir%/public (%kernel.project_dir%/web for Symfony < 4.0.0)
            cache_prefix: ~ # media/cache
```

Where your files are generated? You have to add symlink for uploaded image path with public/../media/cache folder then you will see images in browser

Comment: Thank you for your answer Bhain Nakrani but it doesn't work